# TortoiseGit amend merge commit: "show diff to last commit" checkbox is disabled

Tags: git-commit, tortoisegit, git-amend

I'm trying to `commit --amend` to a merge commit with TortoiseGit 2.13.0.1.

For a repository where the last commit is a merge commit, the *"show diff to last commit"* checkbox is disabled (greyed) and checked after i check the amend checkbox; it doesn't let me uncheck it:
[image]

With other repositories, the checkbox isn't disabled and not checked automatically after i check the amend checkbox.

Is this per design or is there some hidden setting to enable the checkbox for this situation?

Comment: Is it the first commit in a repository or a merge commit that you would like to amend to?

Comment: @MrTux It's a merge.

Comment: That is the reason why you cannot see the diff to last commit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is per design in TortoiseGit and there's no way to enable the checkbox with builtin functionality. I don't know if it always have been this way; i couldn't find much "amend" mentioned in the [docs](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/) or the [releasenotes](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/releasenotes/).

There are two options i can see:

1. use another tool which doesn't have this restriction
2. use [zDump](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9549/Capturing-Window-Controls-and-Modifying-their-prop) to enable the checkbox at runtime